# Subscription in Ionic3 doesn't return nothing

Tags: ionic3

I am doing an recipes app proyect with Ionic3 and I have got a problem when I try to get the data from my service.

This is my service:

```
export interface Recipe{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    image: string;
    time: number;
    ingredients: string[];
    elaboration: string[];
}

export interface Data{
    category: string;
    recipes: Recipe[];
}

@Injectable()
export class RecipeService{

    constructor(){

    }

    data(): Data[]{
         const data = [
               {"category": "desserts", "recipes": [Array of recipes here]},
               {"category": "desserts", "recipes": [Array of recipes here]},
               {"category": "desserts", "recipes": [Array of recipes here]}
            ];

         return data;
     }

    getData(): Subject<Data[]>{

        const data = new Subject<Data[]>();


        data.next(this.data());


        return data;
    }
```

And I try to get this data in my Page like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-recipes-categories',
  templateUrl: 'recipes-categories.html',
})
export class RecipesCategoriesPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription;
  public categories: string[];
  public data: Data[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private recipeService: RecipeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){


    this.subscription = this.recipeService.getData().subscribe((data: Data[]) => {
      this.data = data;
     })


  }

  ngOnDestroy(){

  }

}
```

When I make a console.log(this.data) I get "undefined". I have got another services like that and works fine. I really don't underestand what's happening.

PD: All the imports are fine.

Comment: Try `getData(): Observable<Data[]>{}` instead  `getData(): Subject<Data[]>{}`